# How do you select a date range in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, timestamp

I have a timestamp field in a postgres database.  I would like to select all dates that have happened within the last month. So something like select * from table where timestamp > (current timestamp - 1 month).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select * from table where timestamp > now() - interval '1 month'
```

Comment: (If this was Rails, replace `timestamp` with `created_at`)

Answer (score 5):

To be precise:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  ts_col >  now() - interval '1 month'
AND    ts_col <= now();
```