# Selecting all rows more than 24 hours old in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, date, subquery

I'm developing a prototype database to store flight bookings and I need to be able to select all rows with a booking date older than 24hrs and a status of 'H'. So far, I've got this:

```
SELECT * FROM FlightBooking WHERE ((extract (epoch from (NOW() - (SELECT BookingTime FROM FlightBooking))))/3600) > 24 AND Status = 'H';
```

but this fails with the error "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" when there is more than one row which meets the criterion.

I know *why* it fails, but I can't think of a way to solve it?

Also, yes, I am aware that most DBMSs have functions which would make this comparison much easier but, to my knowledge, postgres doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942219/how-do-you-select-a-date-range-in-postgres

Comment: You don't need the subquery. Just the where clause (IMHO this would also be so for other DBMSses)

Comment: @Robert This is not a duplicate. The time window in that question is logically different from this one.

Comment: Simply subtract an [`interval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) from `now()`:
`SELECT * FROM flightbooking WHERE status = 'H' AND bookingtime < (now() - interval '24h')`